# Ramaze doesn't expose mixins

Tags: ruby, ramaze

Is there a particular reason why Ramaze doesn't expose the inherited index method/action here?

```
require 'ramaze'

module Foo
    def index
        "Index page"
    end
end

class MainController < Ramaze::Controller
    include Foo
end

Ramaze.start
```

---

```
$ curl localhost:7000/
No action found at: "/"
```

Comment: Do you need routing to get `/` to work in Ramaze?

Comment: @tadman - No, Ramaze takes care of routing "/" to the index method in the class. I guess the order of execution may be the issue here. Ramaze seems to load the controllers/methods in a static method, perhaps the mixins aren't yet available at that time?